# Incorporating dictionary code into De Bruijn graph code

Tags: python

This is an ongoing class assignment. There are a couple of things that I figured how to do since I last posted a question. I'm reading lost of bioinformatics algorithm posts and I think I have an idea of what I have to do. In short, we were given a list of kmers, in a text file, that looks like this (without the line space):

GAGT

AATC

GCTC

.

.

.

We're suppose to use Euler's algorithm to construct the superstring. Most of the stuff that I have been reading requires the construction of a deBruijn graph in order to find Euler's path. To do this, I decided to open my kmer text file and create a dictionary with the following code:

```
with open('kmers.txt') as f:
lines=f.read()
spl=lines.split()[1:]
dic=dict((i,x.strip()) for i,x in enumerate(spl))
print (dic)
```

And this works just fine (output):

{0: 'AACA', 1: 'AACG', 2: 'AAGG', 3: 'ACAC', 4: 'ACAG', 5: 'ACGC', 6: 'ACGG', 7: 'ACTG', 8: 'AGCA', 9: 'AGGA', 10: 'AGGC', 11: 'ATCA', 12: 'ATTC', 13: 'CAAG', 14: 'CACA', 15: 'CACG', 16: 'CAGG', 17: 'CATC', 18: 'CGCG', 19: 'CGGT', 20: 'CGTA', 21: 'CGTG', 22: 'CTAA', 23: 'CTCT', 24: 'CTGG', 25: 'CTTA', 26: 'GACT', 27: 'GCAT', 28: 'GCGT', 29: 'GCTC', 30: 'GCTT', 31: 'GGAC', 32: 'GGCA', 33: 'GGCT', 34: 'GGGT', 35: 'GGTG', 36: 'GGTT', 37: 'GTAT', 38: 'GTGC', 39: 'GTGG', 40: 'GTTT', 41: 'TAAA', 42: 'TAAC', 43: 'TATT', 44: 'TCAA', 45: 'TCAC', 46: 'TCGT', 47: 'TCTA', 48: 'TGCT', 49: 'TGGC', 50: 'TGGG', 51: 'TTAA', 52: 'TTCA', 53: 'TTCG', 54: 'TTTC', 55: 'TTTT'}

Now, I'm trying to get this in to build a deBruijn graph with the following code:

```
with open('kmers.txt') as f:
lines=f.read()
spl=lines.split()[1:]
dic=dict((i,x.strip()) for i,x in enumerate(spl))

fin = dic
edges=list(set(fin))
graph={}

for edge in edges:
frm = edge[:dic(edge)-1]
to = edge[1:]
if frm in graph:
    graph[frm].append(to)
else:
graph[frm]=[to]
for val in graph.value():
val.sort()
for k,v in sorted(graph.items()):
print(k+'->'+','.join(v))
```

And I receive the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 11, in 
    frm = edge[:dic(edge)-1]
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

I'm trying to go into office hours on Monday with something somewhat functional.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your line:

```
edges=list(set(fin))
```

which should be

```
edges=list(set(fin.values()))
```

because your **fin** is a dictionary, so **edges=list(set(fin))** will create an integer list of all the **keys**. 
Also your indentation is wrong, but I understand you said you did not have much coding experience.